# How to force removing of an app from an iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

I distribute my apps for beta testing using TestFlight.

A customer has an iPhone 4 running iOS5.1, and cannot delete an app from the home screen. The app was installed OTA via TestFlight.

The app icon has an empty progress bar on it, and when tapped the app does not run.

Solutions tried:

1. Press and hold app icon. When it is jiggling, press x. Press delete in alert view. App does not delete. The app is still jiggling, but now with no x.
2. Tried installing the app by USB using build and debug from Xcode - the app runs, but once the app is stopped the app still cannot be deleted.
3. Open organizer, select app and press delete - nothing happens.
4. In iOS settings, General > Usage, find app and press Delete. Still does not delete.
5. Restarted device. Did not help.

Note that TestFlight lists the app as installed for that user.

Short of jailbreaking the device are there any other ways to force the removal of an app? Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Restarting the phone might fix it.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683464/testflight-fails-to-install-app-and-cannot-delete-partially-installed-app

Answer (score 4):

**Here are some guideline which surely help you in this problem:**

Reboot the iDevice by holding down on the sleep and home buttons at the same time for about 10-15 seconds until the Apple Logo appears - ignore the red slider - let go of the buttons.

Make sure that you do not have a stalled download in iTunes - a song or podcast .... if you have a download in there that did not finish, complete that one first. Only one thing can download at a time on the iDevice so that could be what is causing the problem.

If that doesn't work - sign out of your account, restart the iDevice and then sign in again.

Settings>iTunes & App Store>Apple ID. Tap your ID and sign out. Restart the iDevice by holding down on the sleep button until the red slider appears and then slide to shut off. To power up hold the sleep button until the Apple logo appears and let go of the button.

Go back to Settings>iTunes & App Store>Sign in and then try to update again. Tap one waiting icon only if necessary to start the download stream.

You can also try deleting the waiting icons - tap and hold down on an icon until it wiggles - the tap the X on the icon to delete it. Then try to download again. Try swiping across the progress bar as well.

You can try resetting all settings. Settings>General>Reset>Reset All Settings. You will have to enter all of your app preferences and device settings again.

If all else fails, download the updates or the apps in iTunes on your computer and then sync the content to your iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with EmilioPelaez. This happens to me quite often when an OTA build fails to install (bad provisioning profile, incorrect Entitlements, etc.). Restarting the device always fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google iFunbox and take a look at their website. It allows you to remove an app by connecting your device to your computer!

Also try this trick: Click on the X beside the app. Then hit delete and hold the home button until the app disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Apps From iPhone

Touch the app and hold your finger down until all the apps start to jiggle. You will see a circled "x" in the upper left corner. Tap it to delete an app. When done press the Home button.

You cannot delete any pre-installed iOS app.

If there is No 'X' on any apps you have Downloaded... then check in Restrictions... Settings > General > Restrictions > Deleting Apps = Off / On

If the app is in iTunes, then you delete the app in iTunes (Select the App and Press Delete on your Keyboard). If you then sync with your iDevice, the app will also be deleted from your iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

If your Apps don't includ iOS, you are surely able to delete Apps from iPhone, do all of your 3rd party apps no longer show the delete "x" when wiggling? If so, try the following steps as needed:

1. Restart phone
2. Reset phone (no data loss): press both home and power buttons for at least 10 seconds, releasing when the Apple logo appears
3. Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings
4. Restore iOS using iTunes, also restoring a backup
5. Restore iOS as new, without using a backup

Get more information here to Delete Apps on iPhone.