# TestFlight fails to install app and cannot delete partially installed app

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an iOS app I am deploying via TestFlight.  The app installs fine on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1.  The app will not install on my iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0.  Both devices are included in the provisioning file.  The app runs fine in the 5.1 and 6.0 simulator.

When I try to install the app to my iPhone 4, I get the following screen:

[image]

**In addition**, I cannot delete the partially downloaded app (it's there in the lower right hand portion of the home screen).  I've tried restarting the device and resetting the device without success.

Here is the console output I get from the phone when I hit Retry (stuff in <<>> is redacted):

```
Oct  1 20:35:10 <<my device name>> SpringBoard[67] <Warning>: Killing <<bundleID>> for app installation
Oct  1 20:35:10 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-2645453250453581032/5351851639508112860" requested by itunesstored
Oct  1 20:35:12 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app <<bundleID>>
Oct  1 20:35:12 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: Oct  1 20:35:12  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Oct  1 20:35:13 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.Axitjn/foo_extracted/Payload/<<app>>.app/<<executable>>: 0xe8008017
Oct  1 20:35:13 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.Axitjn/foo_extracted/Payload/<<app>>.app
Oct  1 20:35:13 <<my device name>> itunesstored[66] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Oct  1 20:35:13 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Oct  1 20:35:13 <<my device name>> installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffd8000 handle_install: API failed
```

**Update**

The app installs fine on another iPhone 4 running iOS 6.

**Update**

Similar problem here: [How to force removing of an app from an iDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919618/how-to-force-removing-of-an-app-from-an-idevice)

Comment: I also had the issue deleting the partially-downloaded app. Deploying a development build via Xcode and restarting the device several times randomly resolved the issue.

Comment: I've gone through that cycle several times now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took my phone into the Apple store today -- and, shockingly, they were able to delete the app.  All they did was pound on the delete "x" about 50 times and it eventually went away.

After getting the corrupted (?) app deleted, TestFlight can now install the app without a problem.

No idea....

Answer (score 2):

I've found this is usually caused when I delete the TestFlight WebClip from my home screen.

Uninstalling the TestFlight profile(s) from Settings > General > Profiles and re-installing them usually rectifies the issue.

Comment: So I did delete my WebClip -- and every other profile.  I'm now noticing that the profiles are back, but not the webclip.

Comment: I recreated my TestFlight WebClip profile using the instructions here: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/484900-why-is-the-testflight-icon-on-my-device-white- with no change in result.

Comment: new url for instructions: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829655-why-is-the-testflight-icon-on-my-device-white-

Answer (score 2):

I had just had this issue with an app on iPhone 5c.  I went into Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage > and I deleted the app from there.  It showed it as a generic picture and when I attempted to delete it asked if I wanted to delete null app.  It deleted without issue from there.  I think the issue on the main screen is the system does not actually view it as being there.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this exact issue. What i did to delete the icon was the following. After the error, I tapped the icon and the label changed to Installing. Tapped again the its label changed to Paused. Now when I tried to delete the icon, it worked fine...