# TestFlight error: User gets "Unable to Download Application" message when trying to download a beta test from TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I am beta testing my app, and a few users are getting the error "Unable to Download Application. "Okasio" could not be downloaded at this time". So far 30 users have downloaded the beta of the app, and only 2 are getting the error, so it seems user- rather than app-specific. Does anyone have a suggestion?

The message is identical to the one from this post, but with current iOS 8 formatting:

[TestFlight fails to install app and cannot delete partially installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683464/testflight-fails-to-install-app-and-cannot-delete-partially-installed-app)

Comment: I just had this issue myself on mutliple devices... after 24 hours, with NO change at all to the TestFlight build whatsoever, the app installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that their iOS **OS version is below the app's minimum OS version**.

As strange as it might sound the official Apple TestFlight/iTunes Connect beta system **does not test the OS version at all** at the moment. We faced this issue while we were working on our integration with the new TestFlight system ([Bitrise.io](https://www.bitrise.io/), iOS CI/CD service - CTO here).

For example one of our test apps was built with iOS 8.2 as the minimum OS version. It's even listed on the app's card in TestFlight (*Compatibility*: Requires iOS 8.2 or later) but you can still click on the install button and it starts to download&install it. Then of course you get the helpful error message with *Unable to Download App*.

Note: *Tested on two different iPads, both with iOS 8.1.3*.

Another, less likely issue might be the lack of storage on the device but as far as I remember that presents a different error message.

Comment: Viktor, thanks for your response. I looked into what version of iOS the two users who got the error were using and, lo and behold, version 8.0 as you said! I asked them to upgrade to 8.2, and once they had done so, the downloads worked correctly. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @NickLangan I remember that we were quite confused ourselves when we had this issue and had to test it for a while before we discovered the cause of the problem, I'm glad that I could help :)